# How can I create a vector from struct in main?

Tags: c++

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to make a vector from struct in main but it keep showing error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    vector<A> vertex;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        vertex.push_back(x)
        cout << vertex[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error? Be specific when asking a question here! You probably meant to write `cout << vertex[i].y <<endl;`

Comment: You try to push an `int` value, not an instance of your struct `A`

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a vector of `x` identical elements each containing `A{x}`?

Comment: @paulsm4 Why are you advocating the use of `new` here?

Comment: @paulsm4, drop the `new` keyword...

Comment: Replace `vertex.push_back(x)` with `vertex.emplace_back(x);`. `push_back()` expects an object of type `A` while `emplace_back()` will construct an `A` in-place form the arguments and `A` allows aggregate initialization.

Comment: (1)  You're passing an `int` to `vertex.push_back()`, not an `A` which it expects.   Either construct an `A` explicitly (e.g. `vertex.push_back(A(x))`) or (C++11 and later) use `vertex.emplace_back(x)` which constructs an `A` from `x`.    (2) `cout << vertex[i]` relies on there being an overload of `operator<<(std::ostream &, const A &)` or similar - which your code doesn't have, hence a second error.

Answer (score 2):

x is an int not an A

you need

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    vector<A> vertex;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        A a;
        a.y = x;
        vertex.push_back(a);
        cout << vertex[i].y << endl;
    }

}
```

you can make your original code work by providing an implicit conversion from int to A

also you would need to provide a << operator for A

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `push_back()` an `int` into a `vector` that holds `A` objects.  You have not defined any conversion from `int` to `A`, hence the error.

You can add a constructor to `A` that takes in an `int` and assigns it to `y`:

```
struct A{
    int y;
    A(int value) : y(value) {}
};
```

Or, you can omit the constructor and instead create an `A` object and pass it to `push_back()`:

```
A a;
a.y = x;
vertex.push_back(a);
```

Or, using [Aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
vertex.push_back(A{x});
```

Or, you can alternatively use `emplace_back()` instead, which will construct the `A` object inside the `vector` for you, using the specified parameter(s) for the construction:

```
vertex.emplace_back(x);
```

Either way, that will fix the error you are seeing.

Then, you will run into a new error, because you have not defined an `operator<<` for printing `A` objects, so you will have to add that, too:

```
struct A{
    int y;
    ...
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a) {
    return os << a.y;
}
```

Now, your code will run.

Comment: Won't do `vertex.push_back(A{x});` fine as well?

Comment: Yes, it will, as I stated in my answer. Refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry about lacking info on my question. I'm trying to make a struct Stock. Then making a vector for availability. So later, I can do a pop_back.

Comment: Thank you. It is working as I want it now.